# Twilio: Call and Voice features?

Tags: twilio, call, voice

I am trying to implement a call feature in my xamarin forms app using `Twilio`. I am able to call by providing From and To numbers using [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls) API of `Twilio`. But the above call is happening via Twilio, I need to make a call via the internet (**App to App**). Is there any way to do this using Twilio?

Also is there a way to send a voice clip if the call is not answered? And any way to list out all the voices? I am able to list out SMS and call logs, but couldn't find a way to list the voices. I am using c# codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want to make App to App calls then you want the [Twilio Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk). I am afraid we don't provide an official Xamarin wrapper for this SDK, though there are community wrappers available that might help you.

Comment: Using this SDK, is the call happening from App to another App or App to a phone? On the diagram, it is showing an App to Phone and needs some backend support.

Comment: It can do app to app or app to phone. You will also need a backend as part of it, yes.

Comment: I need to send a voice message if the call is not answered, is that feature handling via Twilio API, or is that settings are done by the receiver side?  And any way to list out all the voices? I have asked this question also in this thread. Could you please add a comment for this too?

Comment: You can handle leaving a message on the API side by using [answer machine detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection) and then [<Play>](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play) or [<Say>](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say) to send the message. As for voices, there is no API, but they are [listed here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#polly-standard-and-neural-voices).

Comment: I found 2 voice packages in Nuget Package Manager, what is the use of these packages?
Twilio.Voice.Android.XamarinBindings, Twilio.Voice.iOS.XamarinBindings

Comment: Those packages are not published or created by Twilio, so they are not officially supported. They may work though, so you might want to try them.

Comment: Could you share any blogs related to these pacakges?

Comment: I don’t know any blog posts about them, so all I can advise is that you search for them, because that’s all I’d be doing.